# How to create user manageable business rules in .Net Core

Tags: .net-5

I am looking to create an application that can process requests and return response based on some rules.
User must have an option to change the rules on the fly. So i would expect the rule to be in Code.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to have the .Net 5 application to run either a shell or python script that will evaluate the request and I will create a response based on the script result.
This theoretically would work, but I don't see it as a reasonable solution.

Is there a cleaner/better way to achieve user manageable rules in .Net core application?

Comment: Are your rules  fully dynamic? Or for example you have one hundred rules that u want to change on the fly?

Comment: Should be fully dynamic

Comment: Please describe more about your rules, What does the user do with rules?

Comment: Create, edit, delete. Some of the rules should run parallel and some of them need to be run in series.

Comment: Thanks, Snackerino, But I need more information about the Own Rules. Not the OPERATIONS ON RULES.

Comment: Oh, sorry.

It would need to get some data from Redis and then compare the data from request to the data from redis.
There should be mainly comparing the elements from request against some of the Redis data.